# A proof for $\widehat{\Bbb Z_{p^\infty}}\cong Z_p$

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, topological-groups, duality-theorems, torsion-groups

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group), the Pontryagin dual of a Prüfer group is isomorphic to a group of p-adic integers.

Where can I find a proof for it on the internet?

Comment: For direct limits of topological groups (here finite), see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2865

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Pruefer group ${\mathbb Z}_{p^{\infty}}$ is the direct limit of the sequence $${\mathbb Z}/p{\mathbb Z}\hookrightarrow {\mathbb Z}/p^2{\mathbb Z}\hookrightarrow ...$$
Applying $(-)^{\wedge} = \text{Hom}_{\text{cnt}}(-,{\mathbb S}^1)$ shows that $\left({\mathbb Z}_{p^\infty}\right)^{\wedge}$ is the inverse limit of the Pontryagin duals of ${\mathbb Z}/p^k {\mathbb Z}$. Finite groups are self-dual, so you end up with the $p$-adic integers.

This is a bit sloppy, since, as Alex pointed out, one has to be careful in which categories to talk about direct and inverse limits. See the comment below.

*Addendum*

Unfolding the definitions, you get the following explicit pairing: If $x := \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n p^n\in{\mathbb Z}_p$ is a $p$-adic integer and $y\in{\mathbb Z}[\frac{1}{p}]/{\mathbb Z}={\mathbb Z}_{p^{\infty}}$ is an element of the Pruefer $p$-group, then $\langle x,y\rangle := xy\in {\mathbb Z}_{p^\infty}\subset{\mathbb Q}/{\mathbb Z}\subset{\mathbb S}^1$ is the value of the character ${\mathbb Z}_{p^\infty}\to{\mathbb S}^1$ associated to $x$ when evaluated at $y$. Here the product $xy$ makes sense since multiples of $y$ by sufficiently high $p$-powers vanish in ${\mathbb Q}/{\mathbb Z}$.

Comment: Silly question. Is it obvious that the $\text{Hom}_\text{cont}(\varinjlim A_j,A)=\varprojlim \text{Hom}_\text{cont}(A_j,A)$ as *topological* abelian groups?

Comment: @AlexYoucis Not a silly question at all. Pontryagin duality is an anti-equivalence of categories, hence it exchanges direct and inverse limits in the category $\textbf{LCHAG}$ of locally compact Hausdorff abelian topological groups. The point one has to check is that the (discrete) abelian group direct limit used to present the Pruefer group is in fact a direct limit in $\textbf{LCHAG}$ (this is because discrete abelian groups are coreflective in $\textbf{LCHAG}$ through the 'discretization' functor), and that inverse limits of *compact* groups can be computed as in $\textbf{Top}$.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Thanks. Good proof. Yet I'd like to see a more elementary proof so that the structure of homomorphisms $f:\Bbb Z_{p^\infty}\to \Bbb T$ will be known.

Comment: @user795571: I added an explicit description - is this more what you where looking for?

Comment: Thank you. But what is ${\mathbb Z}[\frac{1}{p}]$?

Comment: @user795571: The localization of ${\mathbb Z}$ at the prime $p$, realized as the rational numbers with denominator a $p$-th power.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$ is torsion, the image of a character $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)\to\mathbb{T}=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is contained in the torsion part of $\mathbb{T}$, which is $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. Since $\mathbb{Z}_{p^\infty}$ is a $p$-group, the image is further contained in the $p$-component, which is exactly $\mathbb{Z}_{p^\infty}$. So
$$
\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty),\mathbb{T})=
\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty),\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)).
$$
The topology on this group is still the one of pointwise convergence.

Now write $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)= \operatorname{colim}\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}(p^n)$, so
$$
\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty),\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty))\cong
\lim_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}(p^n),\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty))\cong
\lim_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}(p^n),\mathbb{Z}(p^n))
$$
and it's just a matter of checking that this is the required isomorphism.