# The automorphism group of Prüfer group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G = C_{p^\infty}$ be the Prüfer group, where $p$ is a prime. Is clearly that $G$ is a torsion group.

In general, if $G$ is a torsion group, it is not true that $Aut(G)$ is a torsion group.

> But in the specific case where $G = C_{p^\infty}$, is true that $Aut(G)$ is a torsion group?

Remark: $Aut(G)$ is the group of automorphisms of $G$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1048116/

Answer (score 4):

First note that the endomorphism ring of $G$ is the ring $A$ of $p$-adic integers.

Its groups of units (which is of course isomorphic to the authomorphism group you are interested in) [has a subgroup of index $p-1$ which is isomorphic to the additive group of $A$, so definitely not torsion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30572/what-is-the-automorphism-group-of-the-additive-group-of-the-p-adic-integers).

Comment: In particular, the automorphism $x \mapsto x^{1+p}$ has infinite order.